# What does "link" refer to when you delete a user?

Tags: users, user-meta

I'm not sure if this is BuddyPress or not but what does "links" refer to when you delete a user?

http://screencast.com/t/ZeMQUG368t

Answer (score 1):

if said user created any links or not, Which  they probably didn't.

[image]

Comment: Quite random that links is the only option. What about comments? I deleted a user and their comments were still there.

Comment: Comments are separate, and not necessarily "owned" by the user in the same way posts and links are.